# Putting additional functionality for Commerce Files/License

Tags: commerce

I am making a files selling website with Drupal 7.41. Using the **[Commerce Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file) / [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) Modules**, I have been able to setup the after payment completes, allow file download functionality.

However the files that becomes available to download is just the raw file.
I want the file, which becomes available for download to be a zip/tar file which consists the

1. File sold
2. A simple readme.txt
3. A pdf file consisting license information, made for that particular user transaction. Like Envato!

Is this automation possible?
Can anybody please guide me on how I may be able to achieve this? Even pointing out the path would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to get started.

You'll need to create a new license type and extend the `CommerceLicenseBase` class (or the file class). When your license class (whose parent class is `CommerceLicenseBase`) gets activated, the `->activate()` method ends up calling `->save()`. Your new class will implement `->save()` and within that function you can:

1. Generate a PDF.
2. Generate or load a README.txt.
3. Create a Zip file.
4. Store that file and attach it to some entity, email it, etc.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for pointing out the way! This looks achievable!
Will update the post after getting it done! 
Thanks a lot!